# mldivide inconsistencies between Matlab 2017b and Matlab 2022b

Tags: matlab

I have some Matlab code that was written in Matlab 2017b that generates two matrices: `A` (sparse 100x100 double) and `B` (100x1 double). When I use `mldivide(A,B)`, I get the output I want.
However, when I try to run the same code in Matlab 2022b, the output becomes `NaN` for all the values in the output matrix.

I have verified that `A` and `B` are the same between versions.

I tried to use `pinv` and the results are similar between versions with some very small discrepancies (on the order of `e-11`). I tried to use this as a potential work-around, but I want the output to be in the form that `mldivide` provides (if there is a way to convert between them, I don't know how).
I also tried looking to see if `mldivide` was changed between versions, but I didn't find anything that I think would affect my case.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Impossible to answer unless you can somehow post a small subset of data that reproduces the problem so we can investigate. Generally, statements such as "I have verified ..." from the poster are not accepted at face value when we are trying to debug problems. I would add that it is not unusual for changes in the BLAS and LAPACK libraries that MATLAB uses for linear algebra calculations to periodically undergo changes between versions for performance improvements, etc.

Comment: Make sure you’re calling the intended function.

Comment: Since `A` is sparse, what happens when you call `mldivide(full(A), B)`? And what is the condition number of `A`?

Comment: See also this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1930570-did-mldivide-implementation-change-in-r2022b?s_tid=prof_contriblnk